# Adding a 0 in front of date error

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to add 0's in front of the single digit numbers.

```
for($i_y=1950; $i<=2012; $i++) $years[]=$i_y;
for($i_m=1; $i<=12; $i++) $months[]=$i_m;
for($i_d=1; $i<=31; $i++) $days[]=$i_d;
```

tried

```
for($i_y=1950; $i<=2012; $i++) $years[]=$i_y;
for($i_m=01; $i<=12; $i++) $months[]=$i_m;
for($i_d=01; $i<=31; $i++) $days[]=$i_d;
```

it wasn't that simple, whats the correct way?

it's for a select options

**Example**

```
for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
$months=$i;

echo '<select name="month" select id="month">';
echo '<option value="">' . __("0" ) . '</option>';
foreach($months as $month){
$selected = '';
echo '<option value="' . $month . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $month . '</option>';
                    }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Can't really zero-pad actual numeric values. Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yea they are options for a selection box and the format it needs to be saved is is 2012-04-22. it can't be 2012-4-22

Comment: You can zero-pad the 'number' you're storing in the array, but to use it as an iterator in your `for` loop it needs to be a number. Use @kuba's method below: `$months[]=str_pad( $i_m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `str_pad`:

```
$x = "1";
echo $x; // will output "1"
$y = str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $y; // will output "01"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I'm using a select options, where would I implement that?

Comment: I updated the question to show it; however @Tieson T already showed me how. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Craig kuba deserves 100% of the credit - I just took you that last step. Nice work, kuba. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to format a date like '2012-04-01' you can do this with [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
 $formatted_date = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
```